# OAuth2RestTemplate.postForEntity RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for [org.x.xx] and content type [application/json]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, oauth2resttemplate

I'm using `OAuth2RestTemplate` to query an external api that accept a JSON object.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
HttpEntity<XX> request = new HttpEntity<>(xX, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = oAuth2RestTemplate.postForEntity(url , request, String.class);
```

And I got this error :

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for [com.yy.XX] and content type [application/json]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:956) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

I tried to add `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to my oAuth2RestTemplate but I got the same error.

Comment: Can you put the content of SubscriptionAssignmentDTO and the request body?

Comment: It's a complex class that I mentioned with XX in the first block of code, it's the object that I want to send

Comment: Solved, XX class must have a no args constructor